# Google Apps Script "Unsupported add-on"

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

Background:

I started a new Google Apps Script project on November 1, 2018. The project creates a custom GMail add-on. Things were working. Then, on November 14th, Google released some features for the CardService:

> The Card service has been extended with the following new classes and methods that let you to customize the background of text button widgets:
>       TextButtonStyle
>       TextButton.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor)
>       TextButton.setDisabled(disabled)
>       TextButton.setTextButtonStyle(textButtonStyle)

So, I started using some of these (poorly documented) new features. As an example:

```
CardService.newTextButton()
              .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
              .setText("Filled Button Verb")
```

This was appended to a CardService CardSection that was totally fine. When saving this code, the GMail Custom Add-on displayed the following error message:

> Unsupported add-on
>   Please refresh the Gmail app to use this Add-on.

- I try refreshing the page: get same error message.
- I quit chrome and reload the page: get same error message.
- I load incognito tab: get same error message.
- I MANUALLY COPY AND DEPLOY the project: get same error message.

When the code is removed and saved, the error message goes away and the Custom Add-on works as it did before.

[image]

Comment: Search the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)  Consider creating a new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code helped me to get this to work.

I ensured my app is upgraded to a Google cloud project (GCP). This means it's a gsuite add-on, and not a script Gmail add on. It looks like they're transitioning from script apps to gsuite.

Maybe this was the reason you were struggling?!

Comment: Yes - I actually did circle back to this and buttons constructed in this way ***do*** work now. I bet my project was silently upgraded to a GSuite Add-on.